# Missing module files after local python package install

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, setuptools

I am creating a Python3 package. The directory structure is

```
mypack/
  setup.py
  mypack/
    __init__.py
    bright.py
    button.py
  tests/
    test_main.py
```

The contents of `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="mypack",
    version="1",
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

I then run these commands:

```
$ python3 setup.py sdist
$ virtualenv -p python3 /tmp/python
$ /tmp/python/bin/python3 setup.py install
```

The last command generates output the end of which is

```py
    ...
    Processing mypack-1-py3.7.egg
    Copying mypack-1-py3.7.egg to /tmp/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages
    Adding mypack 1 to easy-install.pth file

    Installed /tmp/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mypack-1-py3.7.egg
    Processing dependencies for mypack==1
    Finished processing dependencies for mypack==1
```

However, when I look in `/tmp/python` I do **not** see the files `bright.py` or `button.py` anywhere. Where are they?

Comment: Running `ls /tmp/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mypack` yields `ls: cannot access '/tmp/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mypack': No such file or directory`.

Comment: Everything is inside `/tmp/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mypack-1-py3.7.egg` which is an importable zip-archive.

Comment: Is there no `setup.py` command to install the package without hiding the files inside of a zip file? When I look at all the _other_ packages installed on my system they are right out in the open.

Comment: Set [`zip_safe=False`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#setting-the-zip-safe-flag) in `setup.py`. Or install using `/tmp/python/bin/pip install .`

Comment: The `/tmp/python/bin/pip install` worked.